# How to calculate the resistance to heat a resistor to a specific temperature

Tags: resistance, temperature, heat, wire

Let's say I'm planning to buy some length of Kanthal-A1 wire. To power it, I have a 120 volt, maximum 20 amp power supply (my wall outlet). That part is okay. The problem is, I want it to be able to reach a certain temperature (1200 c), but the only thing I can control is the resistance! How can I figure out the max temp it'll be able to reach by only controlling the resistance?

Comment: Use a thermocouple to regulate the heat because without knowledge of the thermal losses it’s impossible to know.

Comment: @Transistor, Thanks, but I need to know a mathematical way to calculate the heat given off by the wire, because I am maxing out my power supply. I am not worried my wire will get too hot (which can be regulated), but I am worried that it may not get hot enough.

Comment: You need some real physics here, and a perfect ideal set of conditions...

Comment: At that temperature, approximating losses will be nearly impossible, since a lot will be from radiation as well as convection. Both of which are environmental dependent.

Comment: @Rafael: I understand. The thing is that the heat calculation is very simple: it's the power dissipated in the heater and is given by \$ P = VI \$. The problem is that equilibrium *temperature* is achieved when the heat losses are equal to the power in. This then becomes a physics problem rather than an electrical engineering one.

Comment: @Transistor , Assuming a perfect environment, how does one convert from power to an actual change in temperature?

Comment: @Rafael: What is a perfect environment? If it's one with no losses then a tiny power will cause a continuous rise in temperature to infinity. As explained in the comments: you need work out the heat losses through radiation (infra red from your wire), convection (movement of the gas surrounding your wire) and conduction (through the electrical wires and the case which is being heated by radiation and convection). Read up on thermal U-values (W/m²K) and R-values (K m²/W) and start working out your losses.

Comment: @Transistor, Even with known losses how do I figure out the temperature rise? Even if any tiny amount of current will heat up a wire over time, what equation can be used to calculate this?

Comment: The answer is in the R-value units, K m²/W. You determine the power (W), you work out the surface area (m²) and calculate the temperature rise (K).

Comment: @Transistor, Just one thing. What value must that formula be equal to? I can plug in watts and surface area, but in order to solve for temperature rise it must be equal to something!

Comment: You will nead to measure that. Put in a known power level, allow the temperature to stabilise, measure the inside and outside temperatures, calculate the ΔT and go from there. This is similar to calculating the temperature rise of a transistor mounted to a heatsink and you may find some insights by studying that.